# Show "word" singular if there is only one entry in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a span like this:

```
<p> <span>{{ queue_count }} </span> </p>
```

`queue_count` sometimes may contain 0 or 1 entry and sometimes greater. If queue_count is less than or equals to 1 I want to show `{{ queue_count }} entry` otherwise `{{ queue_count }} entries`, How can I do that?

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you use some kind of templating system or what's with the brackets?

Comment: Why would you do this in jQuery? It looks like you're using Laravel, just use PHP to do it

Comment: Could you post your jQuery code?

Comment: Edited, this question had nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple. Use if else condition.

```
if(queue_count <= 1) {
   <p> <span>{{ queue_count }} entry </span> </p>
} else {
    <p> <span>{{ queue_count }} entries </span> </p>
}
```

Comment: change the <= to == it should be 0 entries not 0 entry ;-) other than that this is the right answer.

Comment: @RickCalder The OP want that if there is 1 or less than 1 value. so I use <=.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact it's bad grammar, I'd personally make the change to make it right and note that fact.

Comment: The OP may not have realized that "0 entry" is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<p> <span>{{ queue_count }} (queue_count == 1)?'entry':'entries' </span> </p>
```